# Origin of the term "grounded"

Tags: expressions

What is the origin of the term "grounded", as in "it keeps me grounded"? Does it simply come from the ground itself, which is to say keeping one's feet on the ground, or does it refer to "ground" in the electrical sense?

Comment: Aviation slang?

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 3):

The word **grounded** is from [(adj.) "learned," late 14c.; "firmly fixed or established," 1540s, past participle adjective from ground (v.). Electrical sense is from 1889. Meaning "having been denied privileges" is from 1940s. Dickens had room-ridden "confined to one's room."](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=grounded&allowed_in_frame=0)

It's an early construction term:

> **GROUND**, to fetor lay a thing on the ground; to lay a ground-work; to take for a foundation ; ro raise an argument upon.
>
> **GROUNDED** (of gjnunb.oa*.) sounded, built or resting upon, sustained by.
>
> **GROUNDLESS** (?Jiun?lear, 5a*.) without ground, foundation or reason.

-An universal etymological English dictionary ... v. 2. Bailey, N. (Nathan), d. 1742.

Comment: Hmm. that's funny. I always imagined it as being the opposite of someone who built castles in the air :)

Answer (score -1):

I think it comes from aviation. When planes are not allowed to fly and they are "grounded". I actually worked at an airport during 9/11 and all planes were grounded for most of the day.

Comment: But _it keeps me grounded_ in the OP's question seems to mean something like "it keeps me realistic", whereas _grounded_ in the aviation sense is more a punitive inability to go out somewhere, isn't it?

Comment: "Grounded" dates back well before aeroplanes.

Answer (score -1):

It comes from the old telegraph signals. If you were grounded then you were not able to send or receive telegraph signals because your wire was connected to a ground stopping transmissions which was long before any kind of aeroplane was invented.